# What is the answer for this computational analysis problem?

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Two algorithms have the same function, while algorithm A has computational complexity O(2^N) and algorithm B has computational complexity O(N^10). Suppose a real computer can continuously run 10^7seconds, performing 10^3 basic operations per second.
In this computer environment, please answer the following questions.
A) What is the approximate range of N for algorithms A and B, respectively?
B) Which algorithm is more suitable in the environment? Why?

Comment: Please take a look at this meta policy: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) If you work through the first steps of the problem, it will help you answer the second half.

Comment: Even for N as small as 3, the algo A performs multiple times better. Do you have a doubt on using A !!?

Comment: The answer is in between 0 to an arbitrary time? I don't even get these questions. Asymptotic run-time tells you very little about seconds.

Comment: I vote to close the question for lack of details. It nees info on how the givn duration and the operation per seconds map to O() notation. I think the given info is noise could be ignored a devious trick by some teachers....). Calculating the "range" (whatever that is supposed to be) however has the same problem and makes at least part of the question unanswerable. Not even calculcating a break even point is possible with the given information, keeping in mind that arbitrary factors are not carried by O() notation.

Answer (score 2):

The question is defective.

The fact that A has complexity O(2<sup>*N*</sup>) means the number of basic operations (presumably modeled as each basic operation taking the same amount of time) means A takes at most some constant times 2<sup>*N*</sup> steps for *N* at least some threshold *N*<sub>0</sub>. Similarly, the fact B has complexity O(*N*<sup>10</sup>) means B takes at most some constant times *N*<sup>10</sup> steps for *N* at least some threshold *N*<sub>1</sub>. However, they may be different constants; the number of steps for A is at most *C*<sub>0</sub>2<sup>*N*</sup> and the number of steps for B is at most *C*<sub>1</sub>*N*<sup>10</sup>, and they may have different thresholds *N*<sub>0</sub> and *N*<sub>1</sub>.

In asking about a computer that can perform 10<sup>3</sup> basic operations for 10<sup>7</sup> seconds, the question asks for which *N* is the number of steps of A or B known to be at most 10<sup>10</sup>. In other words, it asks to solve for *N* in *C*<sub>0</sub>2<sup>*N*</sup> ≤ 10<sup>10</sup> and in *C*<sub>1</sub>*N*<sup>10</sup> ≤ 10<sup>10</sup>.

These are clearly unsolvable without knowing *C*<sub>0</sub> and *C*<sub>1</sub>, about which the question gives no information.

Further, we do not know the thresholds *N*<sub>0</sub> and *N*<sub>1</sub> where these bounds are known to apply. So even if we knew *C*<sub>0</sub> and *C*<sub>1</sub>, we would not know any bound on how many steps the algorithms take for any particular *N*.

The question is also defective in that it neglects that the O notation puts only an upper bound on the algorithm. The algorithm may run in fewer steps than the values of the formulae. So it may be that, even with *N* for which *C*<sub>0</sub>2<sup>*N*</sup> ≤ *C*<sub>1</sub>*N*<sup>10</sup>, algorithm B is better, or vice-versa.

Possibly it is intended that some simplifying assumptions are intended, such as *C*<sub>0</sub> = *C*<sub>1</sub> = 1, *N*<sub>0</sub> = *N*<sub>1</sub> = 0, and each algorithm takes exactly the number of steps of its formula. Then it is easy to solve 2<sup>*N*</sup> ≤ 10<sup>10</sup> (N is at most about 33.22) and *N*<sup>10</sup> = 10<sup>10</sup> (N ≤ 10). However, if these assumptions are intended, then the author has missed the point of O notation; it characterizes a fundamental nature of an algorithm; it does not quantify its actual number of steps.